# JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: oracle.jbo.AttrValException, msg=JBO-27035: Attribute SchemaName is required

Tags: oracle-adf

I am getting this exception:
JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: oracle.jbo.AttrValException, msg=JBO-27035: Attribute SchemaName is required. 
does anyone have any idea what should I check? or which schema name is required?

Answer (score 1):

Is any of your Attribute Name is 'SchemaName' ? If yes , then Either in your EO or VO uncheck the required checkBox or populated the the attribute value programatically. This would depend how your application is designed.

-Sid